# Change width of Android toolbar logo

Tags: android, android-toolbar

As the android document suggest, I have set the logo in toolbar. Refer: [toolBar.setLogo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar#setLogo(int))

Is there any way to change the width of toolbar logo?

Comment: this should help you --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/38202628/12553303

Comment: @Wini The reference shared by you is updating the homeButton drawable with custom one. I am using setLogo method which is similar to set title where we set string as title.

Comment: so you still havent found solution or still looking?

Comment: have you went through this--> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27135685/appcompat-v21-toolbar-changing-logo-size

Comment: @Wini Right now I have resized the logo for a better view, but the problem is, it looks fine in phone but then little variation for tablets. Still finding the solution. The 2nd link you have provided is also having the a customized toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

Customize toolbar by creating child views inside toolbar

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar_top"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/action_bar_bkgnd"
app:theme="@style/ToolBarTheme" >


 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

     <ImageView
       android:layout_width="200dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/yourlogo"
     >

 </RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: I am directly using setLogo method & passing drawable.